# Calculate chromatic number from chromatic polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the chromatic number of a graph knowing only the chromatic polynomial, but not the actual graph. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Properties) for Chromatic Polynomials:

> The chromatic polynomial includes at least as much information about the colorability of G as does the chromatic number. Indeed, the chromatic number is the smallest positive integer that is not a zero of the chromatic polynomial,
> $$ \chi_G = \min \{k \in \mathbb N ~|~ P_G(k) > 0 \} $$

---

I hope this helps ^_^